# Update attributes during edit session using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, editing, vb.net

I have made an attempt to create an ArcObjects addin to help with some workflows here in the office.  I apologize in advance if I have something fundamentally wrong with the code.  This is my first ArcObjects endeavor. Essentially I have geodatabases with a large number of feature classes.  Each feature class has the fields "DateModified" and "ModifiedBy" and I am hoping to populate them as edits are made.  I am aware of editor tracking currently in ArcGIS, but the powers that be would like to track edits without changing current data models.

It appears that the code below crashes ArcMap when it attempts to store the feature.

So my questions are 1) Can someone tell me why my code causes ArcMap to crash? 2) Are there easier ways to accomplish what I have been tasked with?  Thanks in advance.

I have the following code:

```
Public Class TrackEditsExtension
    Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    'Invoked when the Editor Extension is loaded
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStartup()
        AddHandler Events.OnStartEditing, AddressOf Events_OnStartEditing
        AddHandler Events.OnStopEditing, AddressOf Events_OnStopEditing
    End Sub
    'Invoked at the start of the Editor Session
    Private Sub Events_OnStartEditing()
        AddHandler Events.OnCreateFeature, AddressOf Events_OnCreateChangeFeature
        AddHandler Events.OnChangeFeature, AddressOf Events_OnCreateChangeFeature
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Editor tracking extension enabled.")
    End Sub
    'Invoked at the end of the Edit session
    Private Sub Events_OnStopEditing()
        RemoveHandler Events.OnCreateFeature, AddressOf Events_OnCreateChangeFeature
        RemoveHandler Events.OnChangeFeature, AddressOf Events_OnCreateChangeFeature
    End Sub
    'Invoked when a feature is created or modified
    Private Sub Events_OnCreateChangeFeature(ByVal obj As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IObject)
        Dim feature As IFeature = CType(obj, IFeature)
        Dim dateIndex As Integer = feature.Fields.FindField("DateModified")
        Dim nameIndex As Integer = feature.Fields.FindField("ModifiedBy")
        Dim changeMade As Boolean = False
        If dateIndex > 0 Then
            feature.Value(dateIndex) = DateTime.Now
            changeMade = True
        End If
        If nameIndex > 0 Then
            feature.Value(nameIndex) = Environ("USERNAME")
            changeMade = True
        End If
        If changeMade = True Then
            feature.Store()
        End If

    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnShutdown()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Comment out the Store call.  http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000007wv000000 `Store should not be called inside of edit events, such as OnCreateFeature, OnChangeFeature or OnDeleteFeature.  Even if you are modifying the geometry or other field values, Store will be called once the event is complete.`

Comment: Great, thank you! I will to give you rep if you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you comment out the Store call, you should be good: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000007wv000000

`Store should not be called inside of edit events, such as OnCreateFeature, OnChangeFeature or OnDeleteFeature.  Even if you are modifying the geometry or other field values, Store will be called once the event is complete.`